# ASP.NET Core Web API : writing to response body is insanely slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 7.0 Web API hosted on a server 2016 bare metal box. I'm creating dynamic ZipArchives and returning them when I receive API calls.

Generating a 300 MB ZipArchive from 800MB of source files and writing it to a memory stream takes ~30 seconds. Writing that same ZipArchive to the http response body takes ~2.5 minutes.

There seems to be something buffering the data I write to the response body.

A list of things I've tried/discovered:

- It doesn't care about Kestrel vs IIS, happens on both
- I've tried controllerbase.File, writing to the response body, responsebody.writer, response.bodywriter.AsStream
- I've tried memorystreams, bufferedstreams(changing the buffer size here affected the download speed), filebufferwritestream, pipereader/writer
- I've tried disabling response buffering features, raising the max response buffer limit in kestrel, binarywriters, nested streams, you name it
- It's not a throughput, memory, or cpu issue. 9 gigs of unused memory at any time, cpu never cracks 20%, and artificially awaiting until all the data is copied to the response body produces a single bandwidth download spike of ~300mb/s so the server can handle it
- I've pulled newtonsoft's json library code and tried to mimic that, still no dice

I can't get it to write to the response body at the speed it writes to a memory stream, and if I start the download before the response body is complete, I can't get over 20mb/s.

I've also tested with/without chunking and setting content-size.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost("patch")]
    [Consumes("text/xml")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileListAsync()
    {
        var languageHeader = Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString();
        var ip = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        string patchFileManifest = "";

        if (patchFileServer.Cache.IsRateLimited(ip))
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Rate limit denying request for {ip}", ip);
            return StatusCode(429, "Rate limit exceeded. Please try again later.");
        }

        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            patchFileManifest = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        logger.LogInformation("Logging request for {ip}", ip);

        return File(patchFileServer.GetPatchFiles(options.Value.RootDirectory, patchFileManifest, languageHeader, ip), "application/zip", $"patch.zip");
    }
```

Server:

```
public Stream GetPatchFiles(string rootPath, string xmlString, string lang, string ip)
    {
        try
        {
            ConcurrentBag<PatchFile> filesNeeded = new ConcurrentBag<PatchFile>();
            var clientFiles = XMLParser.ParseXMLFiles(xmlString);
            String clientRootPath = XMLParser.GetRootElement(xmlString).Attribute("SearchPath").Value;
            int rawSize = 0;

            Parallel.ForEach(patchFiles, (patchFile) =>
            {
                if (patchFile.Value.FileInfo.FullName.Contains("Common") || patchFile.Value.FileInfo.FullName.Contains(GetLangString(lang)))
                {
                    
                    string trimmedPatchFileName = Regex.Match(patchFile.Value.FileInfo.FullName, @"^([^\\]+\\){3}(.*)$").Groups[2].ToString();
                    string clientFileFullName = clientRootPath + trimmedPatchFileName;
                    string clientFolderName = clientFileFullName.Replace(@"\" + patchFile.Value.FileInfo.Name, "");
                    XElement matchingClientFile = clientFiles.Find(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals(patchFile.Value.FileInfo.Name) && (x.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals(clientFolderName) || x.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals(clientRootPath)));
                    if (matchingClientFile == null)
                    {
                        filesNeeded.Add(patchFile.Value);
                        rawSize += (int)patchFile.Value.FileInfo.Length / (1024 * 1024);
                    }
                    else if (!CheckPatchFileSize(patchFile.Value, matchingClientFile.Attribute("SizeByte").Value, ip))
                    {
                        filesNeeded.Add(patchFile.Value);
                        rawSize += (int)patchFile.Value.FileInfo.Length / (1024 * 1024);
                    }
                    else if (!CheckPatchFileDate(patchFile.Value, matchingClientFile.Attribute("ModifiedDate").Value, ip))
                    {
                        filesNeeded.Add(patchFile.Value);
                        rawSize += (int)patchFile.Value.FileInfo.Length / (1024 * 1024);
                    }
                }
            });
            cache.AddIP(ip, TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)(rawSize / 20)));
            logger.LogInformation("Raw size of patch request for {ip}: {rawSize}mb rate limited for {timespan}", ip, rawSize, TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)(rawSize / 20)));
            return patchFileCompressor.GenerateZipFiles(filesNeeded, ip);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("GetPatchFile error: {error}", e.Message);
            logger.LogInformation("GetPatchFile error: {error}", e.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Compressor:

```
public Stream GenerateZipFiles(ConcurrentBag<PatchFile> patchFiles, string ip)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream();
        var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false);

        foreach (var patchFile in patchFiles)
        {
            var zipName = Regex.Match(patchFile.FileInfo.FullName, @"^([^\\]+\\){3}(.*)$").Groups[2];
            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(zipName.ToString());

            using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(patchFile.FileByteArray))
            using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
            {
                originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
            }
        }
        compressedFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        logger.LogInformation("Zip size of patch request for {ip}: {zipSize}mb zip time: {zipTime}", ip, compressedFileStream.Length / (1024 * 1024), elapsedTime);
        return compressedFileStream;
    }
```

Problem: Writing directly to responsebody is ~10x slower than writing to a memorystream.

Desired Outcome: Writing ZipArchive directly to responsebody as fast as writing to a memorystream, and downloading as fast as it's available. Downloading all at once at bandwidth cap after responsebody is complete is also acceptable. I'd like to write directly to the responsebody to avoid having the extra stream.

Comment: @TDummy an example of the code that contains everything necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann You need the program.cs as well?

Comment: FYI "gents" isn't really a thing here, since this isn't an exclusive club... That aside: probably worth editing to show your specific measurement results, and where you're seeing the largest timing disparities, to help narrow down where your performance issue might be (maybe it's disk-based?)

Comment: Just want to confirm, you aren't attaching a debugger while this is going on? 

It may also be worthwhile to implement your GenerateZipFiles function as a async method to reduce the application locking when using Response.Body. MemoryStream operates on RAM and doesn't really have to wait for physical devices becoming available for access, while Response.Body have to wait for network devices and can become delayed. 

You could try modifying your function to stream asynchronously to the response.body and avoid holding all of the zipped content in memory.

Comment: @DavidMakogon There's not much to it, anytime I write directly to the responsebody and try to download real time I can't get more than 16-20 mb/s out of it, but if I run all the writing up front and then download, I get the actual bandwidth I'm supposed to get (gigabit).

Comment: @JordanBrobyn I've tried streaming directly to the responsebody, that's specifically what's giving me the extremely slow write speeds. Also no, not running with a debugger attached.

Comment: @DavidMakogonDo you have the power to reopen the question now that I've added the code and other information? I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Does performance change if you simply `return PhysicalFile(...);`? Will help with finding the bottleneck.

Comment: Not much @mxmissile. I thought I had this thing licked as a client bug, but it's very strange. Some people can pull data about as fast as the server can serve it, but others pull it much more slowly than their hardware would normally allow. For instance, I have a friend with a Ryzen 7 and 32gb of memory, and he pulls data at 20mb/sec. Tested another friend with a similar setup, 150mb/sec. On some level the server seems to be slowing itself to however fast the client can download, and for some reason the client is downloading much slower than it should.